# Create a soil texture triangle

Tags: raster, r

I'm in the process of creating a soil texture triangle based on 3 layers i.e clay, silt and sand. I get the error below when I run the code.

```
library("raster", "soiltexture")
clay <-raster('af_CLYPPT_T__M_sd1_250m.tif')
silt <-raster('af_SLTPPT_T__M_sd1_250m.tif')
sand <-raster('af_SNDPPT_T__M_sd1_250m.tif')

clay.df = as.data.frame(clay, xy = FALSE, na.rm = TRUE)
silt.df = as.data.frame(silt, xy = FALSE, na.rm = TRUE)
sand.df = as.data.frame(sand, xy = FALSE, na.rm = TRUE)

my.data <- data.frame("CLAY" = c(clay.df),"SILT" = c(silt.df),"SAND" = c(sand.df))

cols <- c("CLAY","SILT","SAND")
colnames(my.data) <- cols

TT.plot(
  class.sys = "HYPRES.TT",
  tri.data = my.data,
  main = "Soil texture data"
)
```

> Error in TT.data.test(tri.data = tri.data, css.names = css.names,
>   text.sum = text.sum,  :    The sum of the 3 plotted variables should
>   be around 100: check the data, or change 'text.tol' parameter.

How do I set all variables greater that 100 to be equal to 100?

Comment: Soil compromised by clay,slit and sand. If you add the percentages of abundance of each comportment you'd have a unit. Something is more or less that it should be

Comment: @PolyGeo How do I set all variables greater that 100 to be equal to 100?

Answer (score 1):

To assure that the values add up to 100 you can do

```
my.data <- 100 * my.data / rowSums(my.data)
```

e.g.,

```
m <- cbind(1:10, 1:10, 1:10)
100 * m / rowSums(m)
```

The first part can be expressed more succinctly (3 lines in stead of 9):

```
s <- stack('af_CLYPPT_T__M_sd1_250m.tif', 'af_SLTPPT_T__M_sd1_250m.tif', 'af_SNDPPT_T__M_sd1_250m.tif')
names(s) <- c("CLAY","SILT","SAND")
my.data <- as.data.frame(s, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks @RobertH. How can I map the triangle on the ground?

Comment: What do you mean with "map the triangle on the ground"?

Comment: I mean create a soil texture map from the 3 soil rasters.

Comment: I do not know the package you are using. But generically, it would be something like  `x <- calc(s, fun= ....)`

Comment: am using soiltexture package. One more problem my data points get crowded such that the class lables can't be seen. Hos can I fix this?

Comment: @jmutua I note that you have not yet taken the [Tour] to learn how the focussed Q&A format of [so] works.  I think your additional "questions as comments" should be researched/asked separately.